# get variable value outside the for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, pdf, pypdf

i want to read the whole pdf content.
I have used PyPDF2 and iterate pages through numpgaes object using for loop.
but my problem is i only able to get the whole document text only inside the for loop.
but i want to use it outside the loop. what should i do?
my code is look like below.

```
import PyPDF2

sample_pdf = open(r'/home/user/Desktop/123.pdf', mode='rb')
pdfdoc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(sample_pdf)

x = ''
for i in range(pdfdoc.numPages):
    current_page = pdfdoc.getPage(i)
    text = current_page.extractText()
    x = text
```

I am getting whole pdf content in variable text but in x variable i am only getting last page content.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a list?

```
import PyPDF2

sample_pdf = open(r'/home/user/Desktop/123.pdf', mode='rb')
pdfdoc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(sample_pdf)

x = []
for i in range(pdfdoc.numPages):
    current_page = pdfdoc.getPage(i)
    text = current_page.extractText()
    x.append(text)
```

Comment: Yes, its working, but i want the 'x' in string not in list.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of string gives me the expected results.

```
import PyPDF2

sample_pdf = open(r'/home/user/Desktop/123.pdf', mode='rb')
pdfdoc = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(sample_pdf)


x = ''
for i in range(pdfdoc.numPages):
    current_page = pdfdoc.getPage(i)
    text = current_page.extractText()
    x += str(text)
    

print(x)
```